# Unexpected token '/' in {FILE} while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am working on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k

For some reason, the following line is causing the error in the title.

```js
<% include ./partials/messages %>
```

Removing the line above solves the problem.

I have confirmed that it is not the messages file as there are no slashes in it.

```
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined') { %>
    <% errors.forEach(function(error){ %>
        <%= error.msg %>
    <% }); %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can read in the official [documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)

> Includes are relative to the template with the include call. (This
> requires the 'filename' option.) For example if you have
> "./views/users.ejs" and "./views/user/show.ejs" you would use <%-
> include('user/show'); %>.
>
> You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include
> to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

so instead of

```
 <% include ./partials/messages %>
```

Write

```
<%- include ("./partials/messages") %>
```

Why?

*Template tag <%- outputs the unescaped value into the template, whereas <% 'scriptlet' tag is used for control-flow, no output. The parenthesis and " " are used for filename location*

Comment: Thanks for the input, feel free to add if I missed something :)